# Input psuedo element styling doesn't work on Chrome when declared with other rules

Tags: css

I have an input slider.

```
<input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="70" class="slider" id="volume-slider">
```

When trying to style the track like this for Firefox and Chrome

```
input[type=range]::-moz-range-track,
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  background: red;
}
```

It works on Firefox but not Chrome. But when I separate this into separate declaration blocks like this:

```
input[type=range]::-moz-range-track {
  background: red;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  background: red;
}
```

It now works on Chrome too. What is happening here?

Comment: Chrome has come across something is doesn't understand (the -moz) so it ignores the whole setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is specified to be this way. Invalid selector in selector list normally invalidates entire rule-set. In this case for Chrome anything `::-moz-<…>` prefixed will be unknown so it would invalidate whole rule; since `::-webkit-<…>` prefixed pseudo-elements are historical exception, because they managed to spawn wildly and due WebKit/Blink hegemony established themselves, now the specs explicitly dictates that anything `::-webkit-<…>` must be treated as valid:

https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-4/#compat

> Due to legacy Web-compat constraints, user agents expecting to parse
> Web documents must support the following features:
>
> - All pseudo-elements whose names begin with the string “-webkit-” (matched ASCII case-insensitively) and that are not functional
>   notations must be treated as valid at parse time. (That is,
>   ::-webkit-asdf is valid at parse time, but ::-webkit-jkl() is not.) If
>   they’re not otherwise recognized and supported, they must be treated
>   as matching nothing, and are unknown -webkit- pseudo-elements.

Side note: this exception was added to the standard somewhere around 2018 and presumably Firefox behaved that way at that time already. But as a rule of thumb, if you want to target widest possible range of "unknown"/outdated browsers, you should always duplicate rule-sets with suspicious selectors. (Or do feature detection.)